# What is the reason for the incompatibility between /Gm and /ZW in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[/Gm (Enable Minimal Rebuild)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gm-enable-minimal-rebuild) for VS2017 contains this statement:

> Because the incremental linker does not support the Windows metadata
>   included in .obj files by using the /ZW (Windows Runtime Compilation)
>   option, the /Gm option is incompatible with /ZW.

[/ZW (Windows Runtime Compilation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zw-windows-runtime-compilation) repeats the same remark.

Comment: Too bad my tights and cape are at the cleaners.

Comment: What do you mean by this?